# How to customize a check cart item-action in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart

How to customize or override a item-action tool bar in checkout cart in magento 2.

My actual item-action is:

[image]

My expectation is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can override below two files in your theme to customize checkout cart `item-action`.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

and

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

Comment: How to done custom css for  edit, delete  @rakesh

Comment: you can override this file your theme after comment unnecessary button and after add css in your custom css

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, my question is wrong, i cant customize the edit delete option in your above mentioned phtml file

Comment: then what is problem ?

Comment: already i was upvote  to your answer @rakesh i want  modify the edit and delete action  but i cant done with override of default.phtml  and form.phtml files.